# An internal error has occurred. [CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing a mobile application using flutter and for database I am using firebase. I have created a register page and connected it to firebase, So, when I try to register a new user I am getting this error : **An internal error has occurred. [CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND]**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVd4z.jpg)

I am expecting to store data in firebase.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have added the google-services.json file inside your app directory.
2. Make sure you have initialized the firebase in your app. This basically involves calling `Firebase.initializeApp()` in `main()` function.

Comment: Also check if the application identifier or bundle identifier matches the configuration as in the firebase.

Comment: @AslamThachapalli Thank you for the pointers, I followed them and I was able to connect to the firebase .